# Using node-mocks-http to test a service no event emitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I have a simple service I'd like to test, by calling its controller. I thought I'd use [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http) to create a mock request, and look at the results of the response. However, despite all the documentation and sample code, I could not get the response to emit any event ("end", "send" or even "error"), and can't therefore know when to test the output.

Here's a simple function (using Express 4.*):

```
export function getServiceHealth(req, res) {
  let message = 'service has been up for ' + process.uptime() + ' seconds!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
}
```

Here's my test (Jasmine):

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import httpMock from 'node-mocks-http';
import {getServiceHealth} from '../../lib/controllers/health/';

describe('Service health integration tests', () => {
  it('should get health', done => {
    let req = httpMock.createRequest({url: '/health'});
    let res = httpMock.createResponse({EventEmitter: EventEmitter});
    getServiceHealth(req, res);
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log(res._getData());
      done();
    });
    res.on('send', () => {
      console.log(res._getData());
      done();
    });
    //setTimeout(() => {console.log(res._getData()); done();}, 1000);
  });
});
```

The only way I ever get this test to finish (without throwing a timeout error) is by uncommenting the `setTimeout` line - obviously not the right way to go. And when I do, the data in `res` is exactly what I expect it to be - meaning that other than event firing, everything works ok.

What do I have to do to get the event triggered on `res`?

**PS**: on the off chance that this is some ES6 import shenanigan, I tried this:

```
let res = httpMock.createResponse({EventEmitter: require('events').EventEmitter});
```

Same result.

**PPS**: Opened [issue](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http/issues/73) on repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After opening an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http/issues/73), I got the answer:
The property is named `eventEmitter` - not `EventEmitter`. So I should have written:

`var res = httpMocks.createResponse({eventEmitter: EventEmitter});`

A bit confusing, but I hope they'll fix the documentation to reflect it. The issue is still open (as of 12/29/2015) pending documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the listeners are added before calling  getServiceHealth(req, res);

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
import httpMock from 'node-mocks-http';
import {getServiceHealth} from '../../lib/controllers/health/';

describe('Service health integration tests', () => {
  it('should get health', done => {
    let req = httpMock.createRequest({url: '/health'});
    let res = httpMock.createResponse({EventEmitter: EventEmitter});

    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log(res._getData());
      done();
    });
    res.on('send', () => {
      console.log(res._getData());
      done();
    });

    getServiceHealth(req, res);
    //setTimeout(() => {console.log(res._getData()); done();}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that was not the issue. I'll close the question with the proper answer.

Comment: the property name that mockResponse requires it's in camelCase starts with lower case